# Latest version of cURL for win64 that supports NTLM proxy authentication?

Tags: windows, proxy, curl, ntlm

I am currently using cURL 7.33.0 in order to download files from behind an NTLM proxy on a 64-bit Windows platform. However, it is almost 4 years old and there are now [numerous security vulnerabilities](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/vuln-7.33.0.html) associated with this version of cURL. I would like to upgrade to a newer version, but I am struggling to find one that works for me - I require a compatible build with SSL and SSPI enabled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to upgrade to a newer version, but I am struggling to
>   find one that works for me - I require a compatible build with SSL and
>   SSPI enabled.

You should be using [7.55.1](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) which is the current version of cURL as of today (August 16th 2017).

Comment: Does this version support NTLM proxy authentication?

Comment: That wasn't one of the requirements.  You wanted a version of cURL that supported SSL and SSPI which the 7.55.1 build on Windows supports.

Comment: "Does this version support NTLM proxy authentication?" - This requires SSPI support, the current version supports SSPI, it has supported SSPI  since (before) 2012 based on my research.

Comment: It looks as though this one supports NTLM. What was throwing me a bit was that in previous years you had to get a special version of cURL with these features, but these days they seem to be a part of the standard windows builds.

Answer (score 0):

The [official download page for CURL](https://curl.se/download.html) has a large number of third-party builds, including those for Windows.

As a personal recommendation, the [Dirk Paehl](http://www.paehl.com/) builds are useful and seem to have what you want (CURL is listed along the sidebar).

*Update:*

The [official Windows builds of CURL](https://curl.se/windows/) now include support for NTLM.

**Notes**

You may wish to review the [known bugs](https://curl.se/docs/knownbugs.html), which include a couple for NTLM.